# Trigger view condition change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new with the ASP.NET, and only doing this temporary on one legacy project. I want to display two different divs based on a condition. The condition should be toggled on a click of a button. As far as my research has gone, I ended up trying with using `@TempData`

```
<button onclick="showData()">Show</button>

@if (@TempData["Display"] != null)
{
    <div>Display Active</div>
}

@if (@TempData["Display"] == null)
{
    <div>No Display</div>
}
```

And `showData()` is an Ajax call to a controller

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/borrow/display/0",
    data: $.toJSON({ "display": true })
}).done(function (output) {
});
```

**controller**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Display(string code)
{
    TempData["Display"] = true;
    return Json(new { response = true });
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the view isn't aware of the change that has happened to `TempData["Display"]`. If I reload the page, it renders properly as I clicked on a toggle button. Is there a way to make the toggle without reloading? Or reloading but keeping the view and the model. I know I could do the toggling with JS, but it doesn't fit my needs as I need to reflect the changes in a controller as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use model property for this.
Here is a sample. You can refer it. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
    1. Model

        public class PersonViewModel
            {
                public int PersonId { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public bool isShow { get; set; }
                public int Age { get; set; }
            }

    2. Controller 

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
                    var model = new PersonViewModel() 
                    {
                        PersonId = 1,
                        Name = "Mr Abc"                           
                    };

                    model.isShow = model.Age > 18 ? true : false;
                    return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ChangeAge(int age)
        {
            bool result = true;
            if (age < 18)
                result = false;
            return Json(new { response = result });
        }

    3. Views

        <h1>Details</h1>

        <div>
            <h4>Person</h4>
            <hr />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, new { @type = "number" })
                </div>
                <br />

                <div class="col-sm-8" id="result"></div>        
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <button id="changeAge">Change age</button>
        </div>

        @section Scripts
        {
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    // init the data
                    if ('@Model.isShow' == 'True') {
                        $('#result').text('You can come inside.');                
                    } else {
                        $('#result').text('You are too young.');      
                    }

                    $('#changeAge').click(function () {
                        let ageValue = $('#Age').val();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '@Url.Action("ChangeAge", "Home")',
                            data: { "age": ageValue }
                        }).done(function (output) {
                            if (output.response) {
                                $('#result').text('You can come inside.');    
                            } else {
                                $('#result').text('You are too young.');    
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        }
```